# Custom array super method not accepting the list

Tags: java, android

I have created a `custom list adapter`, i have two `constructors`, passing two different `lists` to `super` methods of `constructor`. One super method taking list, the other `super` method doesn't take the `list`, i am getting **swiggly red line**. Hovering on it doesn't explain anything, error image snapshot is attached.

**List adapter code**

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Cats> {

    //the list values in the List of type hero
    List<PlantTags> tags;
    List<Cats> categories;

    boolean childFragment;
    int categoryId;

    //activity context
    Context context;

    //the layout resource file for the list items
    int resource;

    //constructor initializing the values
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<PlantTags> tags, boolean childFragment) {
        super(context, resource, tags);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.childFragment = childFragment;
        this.tags = tags;
    }

    //constructor initializing the values
    public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Cats> cats, boolean childFragment, int categoryId) {
        super(context, resource, cats);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.childFragment = childFragment;
        this.categories = cats;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    //this will return the ListView Item as a View
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        //we need to get the view of the xml for our list item
        //And for this we need a layoutinflater
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        //getting the view
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resource, null, false);

        //getting the view elements of the list from the view
        ImageView imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        TextView textViewName = view.findViewById(R.id.category_name);

        if (!childFragment) {
            //getting the hero of the specified position
            Cats hero = categories.get(position);
            //adding values to the list item
            textViewName.setText(hero.getTitle());

        } else {
            //getting the hero of the specified position
            PlantTags tag = tags.get(position);
            //adding values to the list item
            if (tag.getCategoryId() == categoryId) {
                textViewName.setText(tag.getTitle());
            }
        }

        return view;
    }

}
```

** Pojo model for PlantTags **

```
public class PlantTags {

    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Title")
    private String Title;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("CategoryId")
    private int CategoryId;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("Id")
    private int Id;
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("$id")
    private String $id;

    public String getTitle() {
        return Title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String Title) {
        this.Title = Title;
    }

    public int getCategoryId() {
        return CategoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(int CategoryId) {
        this.CategoryId = CategoryId;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String get$id() {
        return $id;
    }

    public void set$id(String $id) {
        this.$id = $id;
    }
}
```

**error**
[image]

can anyone explain where the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `ArrayAdapter` does not accept two lists as far as i know. I have opted for RecycleView adapter and replaced adapter and i can now pass as many lists as i want in the `constructor` of recycleview. There are many code available for that. So just suggestion an alternate solution here.

Answer (score 1):

Your superclass constructor has to take either four or five parameters being:

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<PlantTags> tags, boolean childFragment)
```

or

```
public ListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Cats> cats, boolean childFragment, int categoryId)
```

You need to fill all four-five parameters or create a new constructor with less.

```
super(context, resource, tags)
```

Will never work since the constructor that you are trying to call (one with three parameters) does not exist.

Comment: yea @NotZack creating two constructors, this is also one possible solution. Earlier i was using one constructor. But i end up using recycleview which is more flexible. :)